# How do I troubleshoot Wifi network adapter installation/compatibility?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I am a professional .NET/Windows software developer and electronic hobbyist. I've started poking around Linux distributions only recently. This is my first direct experience with Ubuntu and Linux in general.

I have recently got my hands on a UDOO x86 development board. It is similar to Raspberry Pi. I managed to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (5.4.0-26-generic kernel). However I have a problem with Wifi/Bluetooth module which I've recently purchased. After some initial troubleshooting I think that there is some issue with compatibility and/or driver installation.

Here are parts that I have:

**UDOO board:** https://www.udoo.org/udoo-x86/
I believe I do have original x86 board which was part of the kickstarter campaign. Potentially this could be the reason. I am trying to look into it as well. However if someone happen to know or able to get any details from the specs I would appreciate any comments. I will update here if I have anything new.

**Wifi/Bluetooth Adapter:**  [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07TLBNSZQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TLBNSZQ)
WiFi 6 AX200 WiFi Adapter for Windows 10 64bit Chrome OS and Linux Laptop or Desktop PCs-802.11AX 2.4GHz 574Mbps or 5GHz 2.4Gbps(160MHz) with Bluetooth 5.0-Intel WiFi 6 AX200 NGW.

I've tried buch of commands suggested online including
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi

lspci (and several variations) - adapter is not shown here

ip addr returns 2 items. loopback (lo) and built-in wired network (enp2s0).
ifconfig also returns only same two items

I've tried to download firmware as they suggest on Intel support page: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html I downloaded iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0.tgz and extracted it into Downloads folder and then copied iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode to /lib/firmware

Some sites suggest checking if firmware loading is enabled but I can't seem to find any straight forward answer on how to check or enabled it.

Is there a way in Linux to check whether this new device was found and just missing drivers or some piece of software?

Also, included bluetooth seems to work.

Anyone has any tips or hints on how to troubleshoot this or to confirm compatibility?

Thanks!

Questions on the wiki page:

1. Do I have to get and compile locally all or any of those mentioned repositories?
2. How are drivers on that wiki page different from official Intel page mentioned in my question?
3. It mentions "You can now load the driver.". How do I load driver? Isn't it loaded automatically?
4. Under "Firmware_class dependency" section it says I can find the option in location Device Drivers -> Generic Driver Options -> Userspace firmware loading support. Where  is that? And where I can find CONFIG_FW_LOADER and .config

The rest appears to be applicable to when the interface/driver is working however there are issues with connectivity.

Comment: did you read through the [wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi) on kernel.org for the intel wireless drivers?

Comment: No I haven't. I will do that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the link to wiki! I went thru the page but I did not find anything that would be applicable. There are things that are still unclear to me. I will update questions on the original post.